# Converting the string values of List to Date Format in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a string ,and i extracted it to multiple substring and assigned it to **EmployeeNo** and **DateOfBirth**. How can i convert the string of **DateOfBirth** to DateFormat.

The string for **DateOfBirth** will be like **20170101**(yyyymmdd)

```
  var list = new[] { new { EmployeeNo = "", DateOfBirth = "" } }.ToList();
```

Adding the values to list

```
  list.Add (new {EmployeeNo = values.Substring(759, 121), 
                 DateOfBirth = values.Substring(162, 8)});
```

I tried to use **DateTime.Parse** , But its not working. I used like

```
  DateOfJoining = DateTime.ParseExact(values.Substring(180, 8),"ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So, How can i convert the string of **DateOfBirth** to DateFormat. Looking for someones help to  solve this issue. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be: DateTime.ParseExact(values.Substring(180, 8),"yyyyMMdd"...? Your format is different than what you described.

Comment: so, how can i get it into date format?

Comment: Just change it as @EddiePaz has suggested.

Comment: DateOfJoining = values.Substring(180, 8),                                                                 var Dates = DateTime.ParseExactDateOfJoining ,
                                                    "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                                            Even this also not working

Comment: @Muzz what does "not working" mean. do you get an exception. be clearer in what is happening

Comment: Yeah, When i tried to execute . It raise exception **Error 101 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'
**

Comment: @Muzz because list expects type with string date of birth and you are trying to insert one with DateTime date of birth, which is a different error to you original problem. so does this imply that the date parse is working?

Comment: so, How can i get it into date format? @Nkosi

Comment: @Muzz also noticed that the first type has a FullName and the second has EmployeeNo. you should create a strongly-type list and have a class/model with the data. This question is not very clear. you need to clarify exactly what you want

Comment: can you give me an example, i am not clear about it

Comment: The question is not clear enough to provide a proper example.

Comment: I edited the question,please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class model to hold the values

```
public class Employee {
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
}
```

Use a strongly-typed List to hold parsed information.

```
var list = new List<Employee>();
```

and then add the values to the list, parsing the substring to a DateTime as suggested by @EddiePaz in the comments.

```
var format = "ddMMyyyy";
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
list.Add (new Employee {
    EmployeeNo = values.Substring(759, 121), 
    DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(values.Substring(162, 8), format, culture)
    DateOfJoining = DateTime.ParseExact(values.Substring(180, 8), format, culture)
});
```